# mandrill send email javascript error

Tags: javascript, html, email, send, mandrill

I read a lot of pages to get the solution of my problem.

Here is my code.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json",
        data: {
        'key': 'KEY',
        'message': {
            'from_email': 'MAIL',
            'to': [
                {   
                    'email': 'MAIL',
                    'type': 'to'
                }
            ],  
                'autotext': 'true',
                'subject': 'YOUR SUBJECT HERE!',
                'html': 'YOUR EMAIL CONTENT HERE! YOU CAN USE HTML!'
        }   
  }
 }).done(function(response) {
console.log(response); // if you're into that sorta thing
      });
```

And I also has a code like this in the header.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

However, when I run this code, the log says that the email address is unsigned so rejected. I am making a school web page which is not allowed other people cannot connect.

Do I have to verify or do something?